Trying and failing to paste anything with my own implemented pasting logic while blocking OS pasting
I have this funciton:
def low_level_keyboard_handler(nCode, wParam, lParam):
    global custom_paste_enabled_blocking_os_paste
    global is_pressed_ctrl_v
    if nCode >= 0:  # Only handle valid events
        kbd_struct = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)).contents
        vk_code = kbd_struct.vkCode  # Extract virtual key code
        isCtrlPressed = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_CONTROL) < 0  # Check Ctrl state
        # logging.info(f"Key event: {vk_code}, wParam: {wParam}")
        if wParam == 0x100: # WM_KEYDOWN
            if vk_code == VK_V and isCtrlPressed:
                logging.info("Ctrl+V pressed.")
                if custom_paste_enabled_blocking_os_paste:
                    logging.info("Blocked OS Ctrl+V")
                    is_pressed_ctrl_v = True
                    logging.info(f"Ctrl+V pressed: {is_pressed_ctrl_v}")
                    ctrl_v_event.set()
                    logging.info(f"ctrl_v_event: {ctrl_v_event.is_set()}")
                    return 1
            if vk_code == VK_F9:
                logging.info("F9 pressed. Toggling clipboard scroller.")
                toggle_clipboard_scroller()        
        if wParam == 0x101: # WM_KEYUP
            if vk_code == VK_V:
                is_pressed_ctrl_v = False
                logging.info(f"Ctrl+V pressed: {is_pressed_ctrl_v}")
                ctrl_v_event.clear()
                logging.info(f"ctrl_v_event: {ctrl_v_event.is_set()}")
                return 1
    return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)

When I press F9 and stop blocking the OS pasting event I can paste as normal as expected. But when blocking of OS pasting is toggled it's supposed to set the ctrl_v_event that eventually does a keyboard.write(selected_entry) to paste. So my question is can you make the keyboard.write paste from the thread? Here is my custom pasting logic. It's supposed to paste then undo and paste again on every scroll.
def scroll_clipboard_history(self, direction):
    with self.lock:
        self.previous_index = self.current_index
        logging.info(f"Scrolling clipboard history: {direction}")
        logging.info(f"Scrolling out of previous index: {self.clipboard_history[self.previous_index]}")
        if direction == "up":
            self.current_index = max(0, self.current_index - 1)
        elif direction == "down":
            self.current_index = min(len(self.clipboard_history) - 1, self.current_index + 1)
        logging.info(f"Scrolled to entry: {self.clipboard_history[self.current_index]}")
        self.paste_selection()

def paste_selection(self):
    with self.lock:
        if self.current_index != self.previous_index and 0 <= self.current_index < len(self.clipboard_history):
            keyboard.press_and_release("ctrl+z")
            time.sleep(0.05)  # Small delay to ensure undo completes                
            selected_entry = self.clipboard_history[self.current_index]
            pyperclip.copy(selected_entry)
            keyboard.write(selected_entry)
            logging.info(f"Pasted entry: {selected_entry}")

It was working before I added the low level keyboard handler. I also have a mouse listener listening for scrolls. In my logs none of the pasting logic logs from the 2 functions above are logged. Also the scroll only works (and logs) once for some reason.
I'm pretty sure it's a threading issue? But I'm not sure. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. I am desperate and looking for anything at this point. I just want this project to end. Sorry I posted so much code I tried to remove anything irrelevant.
